# Compile a project in TeXLive Distribution

Tags: texlive, compiling, overleaf

I am working with Overleaf. However, due to the high number of figures (and their size) I am not able to compile the project online. I downloaded the code source and Installed TeXLive Distribution.
During installation I think it installed all the number of packages (3961). Now I opened TexWorks (which is also installed with TeXLive) and tried to compile my main.tex document which calls all the other subfiles in the project.

However, I am not able to compile anything, .tex files included in my main are not found and I do not know how should I fix the problem.
If you need any other extra information in order to help me or understand the problem, I would be glad to give it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't try to compile your main document directly. At first get used to your local tex system. Create in some test folder a very small hello world document and compile this.

Comment: I do not want to create my document in TeXLive but only compile what I can't in an online version. There is not a way in which all folders are uploaded with all the files and I can compile my main.tex program? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly there is way. I have no problem to compile offline overleaf projects. But you will have to *learn* how to do it. And learning is better done with simple examples.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike! At least someone else had this problem. I feel better now. In that case, if you cannot give any "fast" tip, do you recommend me any tutorial for easy compilation and learning?

Comment: I didn't compile offline as a fallback, but because I often get asked to adapt files and this is offline much easier. My own projects are all offline.

Comment: Ok. In any case I achieved compiling an article which has all the configuration part (preamble) and text in the same .tex file.

However, I do not knw what shall I do to tell TexLive, the preample is in one .tex file the first paragraph is in another .tex file and the next section in another one. 
Not possible any help?

Comment: Then you can start to fill up the example with your content. Do it step by step.

Comment: Open texworks > File > New from template > Basis LateX documents >  article.tex >[Open] > clik on the green button at right of "pdLaTeX" .... It works? If yes, then problem is most probably in your document, not in the TeXLive installation. Next steps: See the error messages at the bottom  or simplify your document until  you remove the offending code, then analyze the last removed part to discover what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Fran. The test you proposed works. I think the problem comes from having different .tex which are included in the main.tex with subfiles...